# PHP: Sessions check user

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to make a small web society.
I already got the user registration and log in scripts.

When i log in, i check if the user is logged in with this:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
}
else die();
```

Now, my problem is that after it has checked if the user is logged in, it stops executing the rest of the php on my file. I can't see my included footer at the bottom for example.

I also got this problem with getting the profile picture to show, i have set a default picture in the database that is a path (path_to_image.png).

If you want a full look of the code, check [this](http://pastebay.com/136848).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{...}`! (Lines 73-75 in your code)

```
else {
        echo '<div class="box_square"><div class="form_error">Du må være logget inn for å se denne siden!<br><br>Logg inn <a href="">her</a>.</div></div>';
        die ();
}
```

Comment: And remove the die(); if you want to keep running the rest of the script (to get your footer).

Comment: and the line `31. if (isset($_SESSION['username']))`

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball you can store the the user pic in `$_SESSION['user_pic'] = $row['user_pic']` in the login page, so it does not necesary to query the database each time

Comment: So i can basically store all the info of the member when the user logs in then?

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball yes, use to avoid unnecesary queries to the database